# Derivation of Iteration Rules

Tags: linear-algebra, st.statistics, matrices

Suppose we are given a matrix $V$ and our goal is to find non-negative matrices $W$ and $H$ such that $V \approx WH$. So we want to minimize $K(V || WH)$ ([Kullback-Leibler Divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)) where $$K(V||WH) = ||V-WH||^{2} \tag{1}$$ or $$K(V||WH) = \sum_{i,j} \left[V_{i,j} \log \frac{V_{i,j}}{(WH)_{ij}}-V_{ij}+(WH)_{ij} \right] \tag{2}$$

depending on whether $\epsilon$ is normally distributed or poisson distributed respectively. Note that $\epsilon$ is noise. We want to minimize this subject to $W,H \geq 0$. For $K(V||WH)$ based on (1), we get $$H_{ak}^{t+1} = H_{ak}^{t} \left(\frac{\sum_{i}V_{ik} W_{ia}}{\sum_{i} W_{ia} \left(\sum_{b} W_{ib} H_{bk}^{t} \right)} \right)$$ and$$W_{ia}^{t+1} = H_{ia}^{t} \left(\frac{\sum_{i}H_{ak} V_{ik}}{\sum_{i} \left(\sum_{b} W_{ib} H_{bk}^{t} \right) H_{ak}} \right)$$

For $K(V||WH)$ based on (2), we get $$H_{ak}^{t+1} = H_{ak}^{t} \left(\frac{\sum_{i} \left(\frac{V_{ik}}{\sum_{b} W_{ib} H_{bk}^{t}} \right) W_{ia}}{\sum_{i} W_{ia}} \right)$$ and

$$W_{ia}^{t+1} = W_{ia}^{t} \left(\frac{\sum_{i} \left(\frac{V_{ik}}{\sum_{b} W_{ib}^{t} H_{bk}} \right) H_{ak}}{\sum_{k} H_{ak}} \right)$$

Why should these be the update rules? Are these iterations basically the [best unbiased estimators](http://www.ds.unifi.it/VL/VL_EN/point/point5.html) for $W$ and $H$?

**Added.** When we factor $V$ into two non-negative matrices $W$ and $H$, we ultimately want to minimize the error between $V$ and $WH$. In other words $V = WH+\epsilon$ and we want to minimize $\epsilon$ which is the error term. We can assume that this error $\epsilon$ is normally distributed or poisson distributed. This is how we get $K(V||WH)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(W,H)$ denote the objective function (squared loss, or KL). These updates are designed to create a sequence $(W^t,H^t)$ such that $F(W^{t+1},H^{t+1})$ is monotonically decreasing (or nonincreasing, if we start at a stationary point, for example).

Both updates can be derived by using the separability of the objective functions, and then appealing to the [Majorize-Minorize (MM)](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/Colloq/lange-talk.pdf) approach (of which the famous EM algorithm is a special case).

You can have a look at *Generalized Nonnegative Matrix Approximations with Bregman Divergences* by Dhillon & Sra, (2005), where this idea is developed for more general objective functions.

I don't think that one can say much about these leading to "best unbiased" estimators or the like, but I don't know that stuff too well to comment more precisely.